# django-pipeline amazon S3 generates empty files

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to setup django-pipeline with amazon s3. I could setup it in my previous project but I can't actually do it now because collectstatic generates empty files on s3.

requirements.txt.

```
# S3
django-pipeline==1.4.6
django-storages-redux==1.2.2
boto==2.36
```

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)


PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'base': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'css/style.css',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/project_style.css',
        'extra_context': {
            'media': 'screen,projection',
        },
    },
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'base': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'js/libs/jquery.js',
            'js/libs/bootstrap.js',
            'js/libs/html5shiv.js',
            'js/base.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/core.js',
    }
}


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'pipeline.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)

PIPELINE_ENABLED = True
PIPELINE_DISABLE_WRAPPER = True

PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
```

I also did:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
npm -g install yuglify
```

Calling /usr/bin/env yuglify calls yuglify correctly

Edit:

I did an additional investigation and disabled my custom storage and reverted it to:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
```

It did not help so there might be a problem with compression libraries.